# set tcp option on Java ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java, tcp, serversocket, socketchannel

I want to use TCP option : `'TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT'` and `'TCP_REUSEPORT'` to do something with my java application server.

But these option not support by Java socketOptions.

so is there a way to set them ?

does i need to subclass SocketImpl or supply a socketChannelProvider?